# Laravel : $request->hasFile() is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I have a form where I get the `title`, `description`, and an `image`. When I `dd($requests->all());`, It returns the following which is correct.

```
array:4 [
  "projectTitle" => "asd"
  "project_description" => "asd"
  "project_image" => "15940723_1336567063030425_9215184436331587115_n.jpg"
  "_token" => "eUj27iioySvIgut5Afu0ZHMgeVrO99a9e1o7Tw0w"
]
```

And I am storing the values as :

```
$project = new Portfolio;
$project->freelancer_id = Auth::user()->id;
$project->title = $request->get('projectTitle');
$project->description = $request->get('project_description');

if($request->hasFile('project_image')){
   $project_image = $request->file('project_image');
   $filename = time() . '.' . $project_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   Image::make($project_image)->resize(197, 137)->save( public_path('/uploads/portfolios/' . $filename ) );
   $project->img = $filename;
}

$project->save();
```

**But the `img` DB table field gets null.**

The `if($request->hasFile('project_image'))` is not getting the field,

Also, I have a form where the method is `POST` and have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and a for file I have `<input type="file" name="project_image" id="project_image">`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you might need to add -> enctype="multipart/form-data" .... to your form for it to see it as file instead of string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is not in your backend code. Looks like it's an error in your frontend code.

As you can see the output of dd($request->all()) returned

```
array:4 [
  "projectTitle" => "asd"
  "project_description" => "asd"
  "project_image" => "15940723_1336567063030425_9215184436331587115_n.jpg"
  "_token" => "eUj27iioySvIgut5Afu0ZHMgeVrO99a9e1o7Tw0w"
]
```

Your `project_image` is just a string whereas it should have been an UploadedFile object/instance like so:

```
array:4 [
  "projectTitle" => "asd"
  "project_description" => "asd"
  "project_file" => UploadedFile {#30 
    -test: false
    -originalName: "15940723_1336567063030425_9215184436331587115_n.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 5126
    -error: 0
  }
  "_token" => "eUj27iioySvIgut5Afu0ZHMgeVrO99a9e1o7Tw0w"
]
```

Answer (score 44):

If everything's gonna correct in your code, then you might be missing the ***enctype***, I had also missed that at startup,

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Or if you use Form Helper, that enctype easily included with ***file=true*** field.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['store'], 'file' => true]) !!}
```

Answer (score 31):

You need to check php directive **upload_max_filesize** in php.ini.

Generally its size is 2M defined as default.
If you upload a file greater than this size, the
Laravel function

```
$request->hasFile()
```

will return **false**.

Comment: One thing important to note is I also had to change post_max_size to be greater than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: @rick6 thanks man! It was post_max_size in my case

Answer (score 13):

Be sure you have an `'files' => true` option in your form definition like below:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['uploadimage'], 'files' => true]) !!}
```

This option causes that your form will be render with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` option in HTML form tag, which is mandatory to upload a file using `form`

Or, if you are using html form, then make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` like:

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: It supposes to be 'files' => true

Comment: @AhmedAlBermawy thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 7):

I am using Laravel 5.5 and this worked for me (Found it on Laravel Docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#files)

I replaced

```
if($request->hasFile('project_image')){...}
```

with

```
if ($request->file('project_image')!=null){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file getting stored on the server? Because you mention that the `project_image` field is null, but you are never saving anything to `project_image`, but you do try to save to the `img` field with `$project->img = $filename;`

Comment: Question Updated, The DB table column name is `img`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but for me, problem is that I had used `Form::model` instead of `Form::open`.
It should be:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'user/profile/' . $user->id, 'files'=>true) !!}
```